# Insert coment issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing an blog in Codeigniter in which in the coment section, i am having a problem on the insert coment function. It seems that the view/form, Controller and Model are all fine, but still im not able to insert any row in the DB. Can someone help me?

View comments.php

```
<div class="container">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>template/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Contenedor Principal -->
    <div class="comments-container">
      <h1>Coments</h1>
      <h3><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Add a coment</a></h3>
      <ul id="comments-list" class="comments-list">
        <li>
          <?php foreach ($result as $result):?>
          <div class="comment-main-level">
            <!-- Contenedor del Comentario -->
            <div class="comment-box">
              <div class="comment-head">
                <h6 class="comment-name by-author"><?php echo $result->name; ?></h6>
                <span><?php echo time_elapsed_string($result->created); ?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="comment-content">
                <?php echo $result->body; ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add a coment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/coment'); ?>" >
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Your name:</label>
              <input type="hidden" name="post" id="post" value="22"/>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="coment">Your coment:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" rows="10" colums="3"></textarea><br />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view("includes/footer"); ?>
```

The controller coment.php

```
<?php
  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class Coment extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('coment_model');
    }

    public function index(){
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'body', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {  
        echo "<script>alert('Your coment could not be posted');</script>";
      }else{
          $data = array(
            'post' => $this->input->post('post'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'body' => $this->input->post('body')
          );
      $this->coment_model($data);
      $data['message'] = 'Coment Inserted Successfully';
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

And finnaly the model coment_model.php

```
<?php    
  class coment_model extends CI_Model{
      public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();  
      }

      public function index($data){
        // Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college)
        $this->db->insert('comment', $data);
      }  
  }
?>
```

Comment: what happens when you submit the form? Are you getting any error ? Have 
you traced where does it stops?

Comment: On the controller you not call the model function `$this->coment_model->index($data)` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: What are the error you are facing?

Comment: I dont think thats the mistake @wolfgand1983. The index function doesnt need a call and if so, i tried and it doesnt insert anyway.

Comment: No errors have been found @Jigar Shah. It submits the form as it happens, but does not insert on db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code I can only assume that your insert is pointing to the wrong table.

```
public function index($data){
    // Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college)
    $this->db->insert('comment', $data);
}
```

If I read the commented line correctly, the table is called "students" and your insert points out to a table named "comment".

Are you sure the table exists and do the same check for all fields.

If this doesn't solve your problem, turn or error reporting and place the errors in your question so I can update the answer.

Comment: Actually, that is just a comment from another project, it has nothing to do with the code itself. The table is called 'comment'. Unfortunately, there is no error been shown when I submit the form. It acts as it is working fine and it redirects me to the same page as if it has been executed when it hasnt. Any clue of what is happening?

Comment: I just found out the problem. It was the Bootstrap Modal causing me this. Thank you so much for taking your time to help me, lads.